# Is there any way to render a template without layout in iron-router?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteorite, iron-router

Just look my controller code(coffeescript):

```
class @BasicController extends RouterController
  layoutTemplate: "siteLayout"
  onBeforeAction: (pause)->
    unless Meteor.user()
      @render("loginPage")   #----------------->here
      pause()
```

In this case, the "loginPage" is rendered into `yield` region of `siteLayout` template.
But I need it rendered without layout. how to implement that?

Comment: Just remove the layoutTemplate definiton. This should render the template directly into the body.

Comment: @chaosbohne, thanks for comment. "SiteLayout" is the global layout for whole site, and can not be removed. I just want that in this case (need login), when rendering "loginPage", not using the layout, just render directly into the body.

Comment: Ah i understand you concern. Maybe redirecting to another url with Router.go can help you? Unfortunately i dont know a direct way.

Answer (score 1):

The place to tell Iron Router which layout to use (or not to use) is in the `layoutTemplate` parameter, not inside the `onBeforeAction` function. The trick is to make `layoutTemplate` into a self-executing anonymous function:

```
class @BasicController extends RouteController
  layoutTemplate: (->
      unless Meteor.user()
        return null
      else
        return "siteLayout"
    )()

  onBeforeAction: (pause) ->
    unless Meteor.user()
      @render("loginPage")
      pause()
```

In this example, if the user isn't logged in the `layoutTemplate` is set to `null` and Iron Router renders directly into the body. Otherwise, `siteLayout` is used. The important part is the parentheses, especially the final `()` that causes the function to be evaluated and *return* a string or `null`, not the function definition itself.

Note that you could create an alternative layout for non-logged-in users, say that has a minimal navbar instead of a full menu, and put that instead of the `null` on the fourth line.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty long discussion about this in https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/600 and https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/607; I've submitted a patch for this and you can expect the behavior to change.

However, you can use `this.setLayout` to control the layout before rendering. In Iron Router 0.7.1, what you basically want is the following:

```
class @BasicController extends RouteController
  layoutTemplate: "siteLayout"
  onBeforeAction: (pause) ->
    unless Meteor.user()
      @setLayout(null)
      @render("loginPage")
      pause()
    @setLayout("siteLayout")
```

Note that the `layoutTemplate` setting is actually ignored here but you can take out the second `setLayout` when the pull request I mentioned above is merged.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the default template layoutTemplate for each route.

In this case we will just set the **layoutTemplate** to null for the login template only. The other routes will be rendered with the default layoutTemplate except the login template.

```
Router.route('login',  {
        layoutTemplate: '' //set the layout template to null
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>It's actually pretty simple: just pass `null` as your `layoutTemplate` parameter:</strike>

```
class @BasicController extends RouterController
  layoutTemplate: null
  onBeforeAction: (pause) ->
    unless Meteor.user()
      @render("loginPage")
      pause()
```

Comment: As the OP notes, he wants to use `siteLayout` most of the time, just not when the user isn’t logged in. Also note that it’s `RouteController` not `RouterController`.

Comment: It's actually `RouterController` in OP's code. But you're right, I misunderstood the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I just meant the OP's code had a typo, it should be `RouteController` per the [Iron Router docs](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router#parameterized-routes-and-data).